# In Azure Table Storage does CreateIfNotExists count as transaction?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

We have a working code, I'm thinking about transaction optimizations, every time we insert something into table, CreateIfNotExists() is called. Is it counted as transaction? We have many tables, for every custommer several, to have ability to delete it by one transaction.

Would it be better approach to insert data and if it fails with some "Table does not exists" exception create it and insert data again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Every time we insert something into table, CreateIfNotExists() is
>   called. Is it counted as transaction?

Yes. Essentially `CreateIfNotExists` tries to create a table and catches and compares the exception with `Conflict (409)` status code. Since it is a `PUT` transaction, you get charged for this.

> Would it be better approach to insert data and if it fails with some
>   "Table does not exists" exception create it and insert data again?

You can certainly do that. Other approach (not sure if it would work for you) is to check for these tables on application startup only (in fact, this is what we're doing in our application).